# Does firebase transaction retry run codes beyond the transaction?

Tags: firebase, transactions

If there are more codes/logic outside the transaction that should only be run when the transaction succeeds, will these codes be ran after the retry succeed? See construed example below based on my Express route handler.

```
app.post('/some/path/to/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await db.runTransaction(async t =>  {
           const snapshot = t.get(someDocRef);
           const data = snapshot.data();

           doSomething(snapshot);

          return t.update(snapshot.ref, { someChanges });
      });
      // QUESTION: If transaction retries and succeeds, will the below code run once?
      // logic that requires the transaction succeeds
      await axios.post(url, data);

      res.status(200).send('success');
 

    } catch (e) {
       res.status(500).send('system error');
    }
});
```

Appreciate expert views on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for runTransaction [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Firestore#runtransaction).

As you can see, `runTransaction()` returns a Promise. When you await a Promise, and with you code inserted in a try/catch block, if an error is thrown everything after will be ignored, because the flow will go in the catch statement.

So the answer is yes: everything after runTransaction(), the way you wrote it, will not be executed if something goes wrong.

Comment: Does it mean if the transaction succeeds, those codes below the transaction promise will get to run?

Comment: Yes, the code after the runTransaction will get to run